# Can't read from mysql json data in python

Tags: python, mysql, json, python-3.x

I can't get variables in json format from mysql.

My code:

```
import mysql_db
import json

# Tüm kullanıcılar çekildi ve  kullanıcı sayısı kadar döndürüldü
tum_kullanicilar = mysql_db.mysql_get_all("select * from users")
for kullanici in tum_kullanicilar:
    print(kullanici['trendyol_api_bilgileri'])
```

Output:

```
{
    "api_key": "xxx",
    "api_secret": "xxx",
    "merchant_id": "xxx",
    "default_kargo_id": "2",
    "default_kargo_adi": "MNG Kargo",
    "entegrasyon_durumu": 1,
    "defaultinvoiceAddressId": 659331,
    "defaultshipmentAddressId": 5785842,
    "defaultreturningAddressId": 659321
}
```

I'm trying to do:

```
kullanici['trendyol_api_bilgileri']['entegrasyon_durumu']
```

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: I didn't understand your issue in the code. What is your expected output?

Comment: I can't get the values ​​inside the json output.

Comment: So when I try this way, I get an error and when I enter an integer value, it returns values ​​like { or ". kullanici['trendyol_api_bilgileri']['entegrasyon_durumu']

Comment: Can you check the type of `print(type(kullanici['trendyol_api_bilgileri']))`

Comment: Hmm. Output: <class 'str'>

Comment: _I'm trying to do `kullanici['trendyol_api_bilgileri']['entegrasyon_durumu']`_ With the posted sample data, that should work.  If you're getting an error, please post the full error traceback message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the data with `json`,

```
import json

data = json.loads(kullanici['trendyol_api_bilgileri'])
print(data['entegrasyon_durumu'])
```